# Can't get my android service working if my app closes

Tags: android, service, xamarin.forms, android-service, background-service

Hi guys I'm facing this problem with no success in tests, I have been looking for info but can't find any solution at the moment. I followed the guide for services, and did all the guide says, but am still having issues.
My code for the service:

```
    [Service(Label="MyService")]
    public class MyService : Service{

        protected override StartCommandResult onStartCommand(Intent intent, StartCommandFlags flags, int startId){
            var t = new Task(() => {
                Looper.prepare();
                    do{
                        DoServiceWork();
                    while(running);
            });

            t.Start();

            return StartCommandResult.Sticky;
        }
    }
```

And in my main activity:

```
protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle){
    new Task(StartService).Start();
}

void StartService(){
    var intent = new Intent(Application.Context, typeof(MyService));
    Application.Context.StartService(intent);
}
```

I can't get my service continue working when my app is killed, I hope you guys can help me with this, thanks in advance for those that can help me.

Comment: Did you register your service in your manifest?

Comment: @codeMagic, thank you for your guidance, will delete. I thought perhaps, we needed to see an error message.

Comment: @Daniel no problem. But if you think there is something wrong that I missed, feel free to add that. I'm not ***always*** right ;)

Comment: @ChrisStillwell when you decorate the  service class with service attribute, it will automatically registered,

Answer (score 0):

> I can't get my service continue working when my app is killed

Please refer to [this](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html), in this article, you can find this:

> Note that services, like other application objects, run in the main thread of their hosting process.

"Service run in the main thread", that means if your app/main-process/main-thread has been killed, your service will been killed. If you want your service to run, your app must be alive. No custom Service can always run.

You can use [IntentService](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/IntentService.html) to do heavyweight calculation, and at the same time, it will improve the priority of your app so that your app can't been killed.